# Page noscroll keeping scrollTop position in sticky footer layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, popup

I can't handle such a mind-breaker:
It's common approach to hide page scroll when a tall popup shows. But when you set `overflow: hidden` to html and body elements, the content automatically returns to it's top (scrollTop: 0). It's no problem to keep scrollTop position, and reset it on popup's disappearing. But if you use transparent mask, user will see unnecessary jump from current scroll position to the top. How to escape this?
In the current Chrome and Firefox, I can set `overflow: hidden` only to html element to reach what I want, but it's not working on mobile devices.
Maybe someone can propose a good cross-browser solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this should be happening. I would look at the popup code to see if it's the culprit sending the page to the top and using subpar css to position the popup element.

In any case, here's code that ought to counter the behavior you're encountering. Since I cannot reproduce the problem, I cannot test my proposed fix. I think you'll find though that your pop up will be scrolled away out of view.

```
function keepScroll(){
    var x = $('body').scrollLeft() + $(document.documentElement).scrollLeft();
    var y = $('body').scrollTop() + $(document.documentElement).scrollTop();
    $('html').css({
        'overflow':'hidden'
    });
    $('body').css({
        'overflow':'hidden'
    });

    $(window).scrollTop(y).scrollLeft(x);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I noticed the culprit, when I used your code in the fiddle. My problem was in **sticky footer** layout, which set html and body height to 100%. So the conslusion is to check if scroll exists, and to change html,body height to 'auto' if it is. And it's not necessary to save scroll position variables. See the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/m1eav032/2/

Answer (score 0):

The sicky footer layout has html and body height equal to '100%'. And when you set `overflow:hidden` it crops all the content and returns it to the top position.
To avoid this, you should set html and body height to 'auto' if scroll exists (you should check it to keep sticky footer behavior)

```
function keepScroll(){
    var scrollHeight = $('body')[0].scrollHeight > $('html')[0].scrollHeight ? $('body')[0].scrollHeight : $('html')[0].scrollHeight,
    keepCSS = scrollHeight > $(window).height() ? {'overflow':'hidden','height':'auto'} :  {'overflow':'hidden'};      
    $('html, body').css(keepCSS);
}
```

See the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1eav032/2/), for live demo

**Edit 1**
This solution is still not working on mobile (overflow: hidden doesn't disable scrolling on iPad, the position 'fixed' fix for body throw the content to the top), so the issue is open

**Edit 2**
Find a fix, for mobiles. Maybe it isn't so clean, but works.

```
var scrollKeeper = (function() {
    var scrollHeight = $('body')[0].scrollHeight > $('html')[0].scrollHeight ? $('body')[0].scrollHeight : $('html')[0].scrollHeight,
        keepCSS = scrollHeight > $(window).height() ? {'overflow':'hidden','height':'auto'} :  {'overflow':'hidden'},
        scrollTop = 0;
    return {
        keep : function() {
            scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
            $('body').css({'position': 'fixed', 'width':'100%', 'top': -scrollTop + 'px'});    
            $('html, body').css(keepCSS);
        },
        release : function() {
            $('html, body').removeAttr('style').scrollTop(scrollTop);
        }
    }
})();
```

Tip: Of course in the real development you should use css classes to avoid removeAttr(style) etc.
Tested on iPhone and Ipad (iOS 8+).
The fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/m1eav032/5/